# Shinyjs disable textInput not working if output: flexdashboard::flex_dashboard

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard, shinyjs, flexdashboard

am building Flexdashboard UI though R markdown. I am seeing that Disable textInput works if I remove output: flexdashboard::flex_dashboard in the title block.

````
     ---
    title: "without ui and server"
    runtime: shiny
    ---

     ```{r setup, include=FALSE}
      library(flexdashboard)
      library(shiny)
      library(shinyjs)
     ```

     Inputs {.sidebar}
     -----------------------------------------------------------------------

     ```{r, echo=FALSE}

      useShinyjs(rmd = TRUE)
      disabled(textInput("id", "Id", "0"))
      textInput("X1", "X1", "")

      #action buttons
      actionButton("submit", "Submit Changes")

      ```
````

If I include the line `output: flexdashboard::flex_dashboard` it does not work. The textbox is not disabled.

````
                 ---
                 title: "without ui and server"
                 output: 
                 flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
                 runtime: shiny
                 ---

                 ```{r setup, include=FALSE}
                    library(flexdashboard)
                    library(shiny)
                    library(shinyjs)
                  ```

                  Inputs {.sidebar}
                  -----------------------------------------------------------------------

                  ```{r, echo=FALSE}

                   useShinyjs(rmd = TRUE)
                   disabled(textInput("id", "Id", "0"))
                   textInput("X1", "X1", "")

                   #action buttons
                   actionButton("submit", "Submit Changes")

                  ```
````

Curious to know if anybody else encountered this issue and any suggestions on fixing this issue.

Comment: see https://github.com/daattali/shinyjs/issues/67

Comment: @daattali, just checking if there is any update on this issue ?

Comment: it's an issue on shiny's end, you can follow the shiny issue on github https://github.com/rstudio/flexdashboard/issues/29